# How to copy file From Resources?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource

I have an embedded resources file eg: `file.exe` how to copy in directory eg: `c:\`?
at click button
 thanks

Answer (score 25):

You can use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) to get a stream to read your resource from. Then just copy it to a `FileStream`. If you're using .NET 4, you could use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) to make that easy:

```
private void CopyResource(string resourceName, string file)
{
    using (Stream resource = GetType().Assembly
                                      .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        if (resource == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No such resource", "resourceName");
        }
        using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
            resource.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```