# how to copy a file from "resources" to a folder on disk

Tags: c#, file-io

I have placed a dll file in the recources property of my app (from myappProperties>>Resources>>add existing file).

Now I want my app to copy this file to a destination on my hard drive.

Is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254166/how-to-copy-file-from-resources

Answer (score 4):

I usually store the resource file (dll, png, whatever) in binary format (byte array).
At runtime i do this:

```
path = ...
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Resources.binaryStuff);
```

where Resources is the application's resource instance.