# How to store files in an EXE file via vb 2010 app

Tags: vb.net, exe

I need to store files in an EXE file via VB 2010 app. I mean, lets say I made a software called setmaker and one that is called setup.exe. I want setmaker to store some files that you choose in setup.exe, and then when you run setup.exe it reads the files that you stored in it and extracts it to a location specified by you.

Comment: You are looking for a setup program, also known as an installer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best choice for building Windows installers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)

Comment: @CodyGray it sounds almost like possibly a self extracting zip file

Answer (score 0):

The following post [How to copy file From Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254166/how-to-copy-file-from-resources) discusses a method for copying a file that is an Embedded resource in an EXE to a folder on disk.

Hope that helps.